# Change Image when repeat animation

Tags: android, animation

I would like to rotate an imageView 10 times, every times, the imageView will load randomly an image in drawable resources. For example: there are 6 images like img1 to img6. I did the code like this, but it doesn't work

```
public void clockwise(View view){

    for (int i=1; i<=6; i++){
        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.clockwise);
        animation.setRepeatCount(10);

        int max=6, min=1;
        int randNum = min + (int)(Math.random()*((max-min)+1));//
        if (randNum==1) image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die1));
        else if (randNum==2) image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die2));
        else if (randNum==3) image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die3));
        else if (randNum==4) image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die4));
        else if (randNum==5) image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die5));
        else if (randNum==6) image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die6));

        image.startAnimation(animation);


    }
```

It just load only one image that I set in xml file for 10 times of repeating

Answer (score 1):

you can use animation listener like below

```
       animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

}
});)
```

So in onAnimationRepeat method you can change your image.

Answer (score 1):

instead of loop use Animation Listener.

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.clockwise);
        animation.setRepeatCount(10);

 image.startAnimation(animation);
```

Overrided methods.

```
@Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

int max=6, min=1;
        int randNum = min + (int)(Math.random()*((max-min)+1));//
        if (randNum==1) image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die1));
        else if (randNum==2) image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die2));
        else if (randNum==3) image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die3));
        else if (randNum==4) image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die4));
        else if (randNum==5) image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die5));
        else if (randNum==6) image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die6));


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks KDeogharkar and Ragesh for your suggestion.

I've tried to used your way that is changing image onAnimationRepeat(), but it still doesn't work. I guess that is caused because the image is still being used by the animation, so it doesn't allow to change the image. Therefore, I write a recursive function that waits for the end of the animation to change image, and call the same animation, so finally it works. Here is my code

```
public void rotate(int count){

        //
        final int nextCount = count - 1;
        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        int max = 6, min = 1;
        int randNum = min + (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1));//
        if (randNum == 1)
            image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die1));
        else if (randNum == 2)
            image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die2));
        else if (randNum == 3)
            image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die3));
        else if (randNum == 4)
            image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die4));
        else if (randNum == 5)
            image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die5));
        else if (randNum == 6)
            image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.die6));


        Animation animation;
        animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.clockwise);

        animation.setRepeatCount(1);
        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                if (nextCount >=0) rotate(nextCount);

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

        image.startAnimation(animation);
    }
```

After that, I just need to call rotate(animationTimes) in main() function.